# Split rows with same name into multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

My excel sheet looks like this:

```
Name C.p Value
a    1   1.75  
b    1   2.35  
c    1   1.32  
d    1   2.45  
a    2   2.7  
b    2   1.85  
c    2   1.9  
d    2   2.6  
a    3   3.2  
b    3   4.5  
c    3   9.2  
d    3   5.01
```

Like this  4~5 names  50 ~ 60 check points and values at those check points

I want the excel to look like

```
C.p    a     b     c       d  
1      1.75  2.35   1.32   2.45  
2      2.7   1.85   1.9    2.6  
3      3.2   4.5    9.2    5.01
```

Here C.p is check point. it is not always 1  2  3 .. it changes values form sheet to sheet

Could Some one help with the code
thank you

Comment: So, first column is the name of a column, then number of a row and last column is value that should be under specified address?

Comment: Have you already tried something? We aren't here to write your code. We'd like to help but we don't do your work. Show us what you already got.

Comment: I dont know where to start.I am currently using excel by filtering the coulmns name wise.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this exactly, but you should search for the term `Pivot Table`, which is able to do this stuff. It's included in Excel

Comment: Yes Michal turczyn. it should be that way

Comment: yes im using 2010 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the only thing you want to do,You can do it quickly by pivot table in excel itself. You will get some extra columns like Grand Total Which you can remove. As far as effort for removing the unwanted columns to the code it will be quite less.

see the below pic.

[image: Pivot representation of data]

Comment: ThankYou, I there a way to automate the process with one click. this is working fine.